# Read one column if some fields are empty in csv file using java

Tags: java

For Example-

```
a   a       0           12      4

b   b   0           29

a   c   0   3   b   87      12

z   y   ab  81      43
```

I want column number 5.

As csv file has string tokenizer seperated by ",". There may have some fields empty which not counted as tokens.So I did not get fields at same column with same token number.

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your csv file? What part of the parsing process are you having trouble with? (for example, can you open the file? can you read it line-by-line?)

Answer (score 1):

Try using more tested code like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ for parsing CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a whole lot of assumptions. For each line you should be doing:

```
String myString;
String[] stringArray = testString.split(",");//To give us a nice indexable format

if(stringArray.length > 6) //Stops us from indexing out of bounds
{
      myString = stringArray[5]; //Because we want the 5th column
}
```

I've assumed you are looking for column number 5, not the 5th column from the left, as this would be column index 4. (As arrays are 0-based)

I'm not a Java programmer anymore, so please excuse me if any of this is wrong. This would work in c#

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data is tab-separated. In that case the following code should do:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            String[] cols = line.split("\t");
            System.out.println(cols[5]);
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cols));
        }
    }
}
```

If data contains the following (tab-separated) lines

```
a   a   0           12  4
b   b   0           29  
a   c   0   3   b   87  12
z   y   ab  81      43
```

You'll get the following output from the above program:

```
12
29
87
43
```

Comment: You are far too nice... I hope this isn't a homework question!

Comment: No. 
But my CSV file is comma seperated.And its not counting empty fields.

Comment: well make that clear in the example in your question, and split on `","` instead of `"\t"`...

Comment: There may have some empty fields which are not counted as tokens.So I did not get fields at same column with same token number.(Using String tokenizer for getting tokens)